# Css Positioning Issue

Tags: css

How can I move div over images using CSS? I tried a lot but failed.

**CSS**

```
.mytooltip
{
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: inherit;
    top: 250px;
    left: 150px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.myfloorplan
{
    position: inherit;
}
```

**Html**

```
<body>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="Container">
        <div class="mytooltip">
            MyLabel
        </div>
        <div class="mytooltip">
            MyLabel
        </div>
        <img src="Sample%20warehouse%20floorplan.jpg" class="myfloorplan" />
    </div>
</body>
```

**Should be** ....[image]

Comment: I'm going to take a guess here and say that the question was voted down because it's nigh on incomprehensible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use position:absolute; and make sure your main container is position:relative;

An example is at http://jsfiddle.net/Pqz5F/

```
#container{
    position:relative;}
.mytooltip
{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:0;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    z-index: 9999;
}

.myfloorplan
{
    position: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Its not working correcctly when you put more <br> then image goes down BUT labels remain on same position

Comment: ooops u did perfect man :) only mistake in ur code that #container id is case sensitive so it is capital C in html